# Finding a geometric condition for a determinant function to be positive

Tags: geometry, determinant, cross-product

I am looking to check my thinking, and for help to make workings rigorous for the following problem.

Let $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2)^T$ etc. and define

$$f(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c})= 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & a_1 & a_2\\
1 & b_1 & b_2\\
1 & c_1 & c_2\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

I have shown that $f=0\iff \mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$ colinear in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The next part of the question says:

> By giving a geometric interpretation to the condition $f\gt 0$, show that for all $n\geq 3$, there exists $\mathbf{p}_1,...,\mathbf{p}_n\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(\mathbf{p}_i,\mathbf{p}_j,\mathbf{p}_k)\gt 0$ for all $1\leq i\lt j\lt k \leq n$.

I am concerned I may be overcomplicating this, but this is the workings I have so far:

Note firstly all the points must be distinct, otherwise $f=0$. Clearly the condition means that the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not colinear, and by writing $\mathbf{a}'=(1,a_1,a_2)$ etc. we can write
$$
f=(\mathbf{a}'\wedge\mathbf{b}')\,\cdot\,\mathbf{c}'
=\lvert\mathbf{a}'\wedge\mathbf{b}'\rvert\lvert\mathbf{c}'\rvert\cos{\theta}
$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{a}'\wedge\mathbf{b}'$ & $\mathbf{c}'$, so we have that the condition holds iff $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Equally, by the cycling property of the scalar triple product, this same condition holds for $\mathbf{b}'\wedge\mathbf{c}'$ & $\mathbf{a}'$, and $\mathbf{c}'\wedge\mathbf{a}'$ & $\mathbf{b}'$.

(*) Since the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not colinear, they must form a triangle and, based on the examples I have sketched and visualised, I believe we must have that the points must appear in the order $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$ as we sweep anticlockwise around the triangle's orthocentre.

Then for any $n\geq 3$ we can let the $\mathbf{p}_i$ be the $n$ vertices of a regular $n$-gon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the vertices labelled with $i$ increasing anticlockwise.

I may be incorrect with this, and so any hints in the right direction would be great. If not, I would really like some help with making my workings in (*) rigorous. Thank you! Any and all feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Briefly, your argument is good! <> The "anticlockwise" assertion assumes a right-handed coordinate system, which is probably safe. If you want to be (very!) picky, the "actual" geometric condition is that non-proportional vectors $a'$ and $b'$ determine a half-space -- containing their cross product, and whose boundary is the plane $a'$ and $b'$ span -- and $c'$ lies in this half-space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that's really useful. Given that condition though I am curious as to what the most obvious way to use that to construct the $n$ $p_i$ points would be. Thinking about it, nothing is sticking out

Comment: Your regular polygon idea is what I'd have done. (If it matters, any convex $n$-gon works.)